# Removing the symlink doesn't clear a package from the corresponding virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, setuptools

I just set up a sample project via `setuptools`. The `setup.py` is:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='test_project',
    version='0.1',
    packages=['test_project'],
    zip_safe=False
)
```

I added this package to my virtualenv via `python setup.py develop` which placed a corresponding symlink in my virtualenv: `./lib/python2.7/site-packages/test-project.egg-link`.

To remove the package I thought it would be sufficient to remove just the symlink from the virtualenv. However after removing the symlink `python -c "import test_project"` still succeeds. Are there any caches which I need to remove in addition?

(I created the virtualenv with the option `--system-site-packages` if that is of any importance; the package is not installed system-wide, i.e. `python -c "import test_project"` fails outside of the virtualenv.)

(I have this problem with both Python 2 and Python 3.)

Comment: Won't `pip uninstall .` do what you want?

Comment: Yep `pip uninstall` indeed did the job. Probably due to what you mentioned in your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to remove your package from the `easy-install.pth` in your site-packages. It should be `./lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth` in your case.

I find it a lot more convenient to install development versions of python packages via pip with `pip install -e .` from the project directory (or `pip install -e [projectpath]` from anywhere). Packages installed that way can be easily removed with `pip uninstall [packagename]`

Comment: Removing from `easy-install.pth` worked! I could also use `pip uninstall` though I did install the package via `setup.py`.

Comment: @karlson I wrongly installed a module with `python3 -m pip install -e .`, and I tried all the possible solutions which didn't work. Finally, thanks for your answer the package was successfully removed.

Comment: pleased to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me.
It will create a `.egg-info` file inside the directory where we run `pip install -e .`
Go to that directory and delete `.egg-info` file.
Then cross check with `pip list`